# How to list all types implementing an interface using MEF2?

Tags: c#, mef

When I call `CompositionHost.GetExport<IInterface>("typename")` I get an instance of the type requested which implements `IInterface` and everything is fine.

When I call `CompositionHost.GetExports<IInterface>()` I'm expecting a list of all the types that implement `IInterface` but the result is an empty collection.

Either I'm misunderstanding the purpose of `GetExports()` or I've implemented something incorrectly.

My conventions are built as follows:

```
conventions.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IInterface>()
           .Export<IInterface>(builder => builder.AsContractName(type => type.Name));
```

My types are implemented without attributes and just implement `IInterface`.

Is there a way to list types using MEF2 configured in this way? Or do I need to change something in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Exports are described by the export contracts.

The export contract is either a type or a type combined with a contract name. By using the `ExportBuilder.AsContractName` method, you explicitly specify the contract name. Thus, you can only import these parts by their type *and* contract name.

Your first option is: do not specify the contract name.

```
conventions.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IInterface>().Export<IInterface>();
```

Then, `GetExports<IInterface>()` will return all instances of that contract type. However, you will not be able to import a single instance via `GetExport<IInterface>()` because the container will throw an exception caused by multiple known implementations.

*By the way, the container always returns instances. You write that you expect a list of types, but you only can get a list of instances (instantiated parts) from a container. To get a list of types, you need a catalog where the parts are managed. Depending on your environment, you might have no access to the catalog.*

If you still want to have both features (multiple implementations and single implementation access), consider switching from contract names to metadata.

```
conventions
    .ForTypesDerivedFrom<IInterface>()
    .Export<IInterface>(builder => builder
        .AsContractType<IInterface>()
        .AddMetadata("ImplementationName", type => type.Name));

var myInstance = container
    .GetExports<Lazy<IInterface, IDictionary<string, object>>>()
    .Where(v => v.Metadata["ImplementationName"] == "YourImplType")
    .FirstOrDefault()?
    .Value;
```

`IDictionary<string, object>` is a generic metadata view that allows you to access the parts metadata.

Comment: "You write that you expect a list of types, but you only can get a list of instances (instantiated parts) from a container."
Thanks, I mistyped - I meant instances so this works for me.
I wanted to avoid the meta data approach but I'll certainly explore this to provide the feature.